# Create redux reducer to change state nested object value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React-Redux and i am struggling with a proof-of-concept project (list of movies) in order to learn the basics of redux. I am quite good at React, but Redux is another deal...

So, in my repo and specifically in Smart Component MoviesList.jsx (https://bitbucket.org/vforvaios/react-movie-app/src/05a6241eff3a1896eca91bb1800e8e017f8b569a/src/MoviesList.jsx?at=feature%2Fadd_redux&fileviewer=file-view-default) i am wondering how to dispatch the correct action to change the rating (increment, decrement) in each SingleMovieItem (https://bitbucket.org/vforvaios/react-movie-app/src/05a6241eff3a1896eca91bb1800e8e017f8b569a/src/SingleMovieItem.jsx?at=feature%2Fadd_redux&fileviewer=file-view-default) and what would be the correct reducer to achieve that. Could anyone help me with this?

In other words, to show a real example of what i mean...
Lets say that there is a main App and we make use of the

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

And then the App contains the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MoviesList from './MoviesList'

class App extends Component {
   render() {
       return (
          <div>
             <MoviesList />
          </div>
       )
   }
}

export default App;
```

And then, the MovieList.jsd contains the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { addRating } from './actions';
import SingleMovieItem from './SingleMovieItem';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    allMovies: state
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIncrement: (id) => dispatch(addRating(id))
  };
};

class MovieList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleIncrement = id => {

  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div>
           <ul className="moviesList">
              {this.props.allMovies.movies.map(movie => {
                return (
                   <SingleMovieItem
                      key={movie.id}
                      movie={movie}
                      onIncrement={this.handleIncrement(movie.id)} />
                );
              })}
           </ul>
         </div>
       )
     }
   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MovieList);
```

What would be the reducer to increment rating of each singlemovie
if initialState is

```
const initialState = {
   movies: [
      {
         id: "1",
         title: "Harry Potter 1",
         url: "harry-1.jpg",
         rating: "2"
      },
      {
         id: "2",
         title: "Harry Potter 2",
         url: "harry-2.jpg",
         rating: "3"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code using https://codepen.io or similar services, instead of directly putting bitbucket links.

Comment: Since it already has a complicated structure (hence create-react-app) i thought that providing direct links would be nicer and more readable than trying to re-implement the whole thing in codepen...

Comment: not everybody is a user of bitbucket ! :)